# Special Bidirectional Association

Tags: c++

I think it was called reflexive association but I'm not quite sure.

This is the code (It should be enought to see what ist important):

```
CGmae::CGame(void)
{
    CFigure * figure = new CFigure(this);
}

CFigure::CFigure(CGame * game)
{
    CGame * game = game;
}
```

I wanted to create an object of CFigure in the class CGame, so that CFigures knows CGame and the other way round ofc. Why isn't it working with 'this'? What do I need to do to solve the problem?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What isn't working? What's the error?

Comment: Typo: `CGmae::CGame` is misspelled.

Comment: 'this' .... it  '* figure' should get THE object of CGame

Comment: @Jon its just an example code but thanks anyway!!

Comment: What is your problem? Does it not compile? Not do what you want? Your example contains typos which makes it even harder to guess what you mean.

Comment: error C2664: 'CSpiel::CSpiel(const CSpiel &)': Konvertierung des Parameters 1 von 'CSpiel *' in 'const CSpiel &' nicht möglich

Comment: This does not match the code posted. This error relates to a const cast problem. One of your classes (CSpiel) is declared const, but the constructor in your second class does not accept a const pointer

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me (idiomatic improvements and spellchecking added):

```
struct CGame;

struct CFigure
{
  CGame * cg;
  CFigure(CGame * p) : cg(p) { }
};

struct CGame
{
  CFigure * cf;
  CGame() : cf(new CFigure(this)) { }
};  // better be sure to understand memory leaking and exceptions...

CGame g; // works
```